# Is the name Takahashi no Kaedemaro 高橋 楓麻呂 realistic for a seventh century man?

Tags: names, history

I’m writing a short novel set in Seventh-century China (Tang Dynasty). One of the characters is a Japanese musician who travels to the Tang Empire in 653, and I desperately need a historically-accurate name for this character. After doing some research, I’ve combined the names of several seventh century Japanese historic figures, leading to the name Takahashi no Kaedemaro 高橋 楓麻呂 (the suffix -maro, according to my research, was used in male given names for both the aristocracy and lower classes during this time). Is this a realistic name for my character?

Comment: I can’t answer your question but the name would be written as 楓麻呂 in Japanese. Not only the first but the third character is also different from your Simplified versions. I’m pointing this out because you didn’t write 橋 in Simplified.

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer, but I think that for *anyone* to give a good answer you'll need to add a bit more information about your character. By "musician," do you mean an aristocratic envoy who dabbles in music as a hobby, or someone of lower status, such as a flutist in a *gigaku* troupe? If the latter, the name you have chosen is far too aristocratic sounding -- in fact, such a person wouldn't really have had a surname at all. (He also probably wouldn't have been included on a mission to T'ang, but you can chalk that up to creative license.) Good luck -- sounds like an interesting novel!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I didn’t want the name to sound too aristocratic. Do you have any tips on how to change that? Would simply taking away the surname suffice?

Comment: And does the first name also sound too aristocratic by itself? I did some research, and found names such as 古麻吕 and 安麻吕 on peasant family registries; I also read about a slave named 徳麻呂. My conclusion was that 麻吕 was a suitable suffix for a male name of any social status… is that not true?

Comment: By "first name" you mean "given name," right? It's true that during this period given names ending in -maro were very common among men, including commoners. But I just don't know enough to advise you on whether Kaedemaro would be an appropriate name for the kind of character you have in mind. (That's why I didn't write an answer.) Sorry, and I hope someone will be able to help you with this!